# How to test if a polynomial is cyclotomic, i.e. divides $x^k - 1$ for some $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Given a monic polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, how can I determine whether there is $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f\mid x^k-1$?

For example, $x^2-x+1$ divides $x^6-1$, but $x^2-x-1$ does not divide any such $x^k-1$ (unless I miss my mark!).

I would also be interested in finding how to answer this for other parameterized families of polynomials, or working over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ - I expect the former to be hard and the latter easy.

Comment: This holds iff the roots of $f$ are distinct roots of unity, iff $f$ is a product of distinct cyclotomic polynomials.  Are you looking for something more algorithmic than this?

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: Yes, if possible: f might be large.

Comment: I've edited the question to specify that f must be monic to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are various algorithms known for such, based on properties of roots of unity, e.g.
[image]
See for example the following papers.

F. Beukers ,  C. J. Smyth. [Cyclotomic Points on Curves,](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.32.8187)  Proc. Milennial Conference on Number Theory,  May 21–26, 2000, Urbana-Champaign, AK Peters (2001). (Section 2)

Iskander Aliev, Chris Smyth. [Solving algebraic equations in roots of unity.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.1747) (Section 2.1)

R. J. Bradford and J. H. Davenport, [Effective tests for cyclotomic polynomials.](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-51084-2_22)
Symbolic and Algebraic Computation, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 1989,
Volume 358/1989, 244-251, DOI: 10.1007/3-540-51084-2_22

**Abstract** (from Bradford and Davenport)

We present two efficient tests that determine if a given polynomial is cyclotomic, or is a product of cyclotomics. The first method uses the fact that all the roots of a cyclotomic polynomial are roots of unity, and the second the fact that the degree of a cyclotomic polynomial is a value of $\:\phi(n),$ for some $n$. We can also find the cyclotomic factors of any polynomial.

Here is the first method:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's really great.  I've coded up the Bradford & Davenport graeffe approach in a few versions.  Question: is there a good way to determine the minimal _n_ when the algorithm reports that f is a product of distinct cyclotomics?

Comment: B&D call this "easily computed" on the sentence straddling pp. 248-249 but I don't see how.

Answer (score 13):

The polynomials $x^n-1$ have as roots the complex $n$th roots of unity. They factor as
$$x^n - 1 = \prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x)$$
where $\Phi_d(x)$ is the [$d$th cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). $\Phi_d(x)$ is defined as
$$\Phi_d(x) = \prod(x-\omega)$$
where $\omega$ ranges over all primitive $d$th roots of unity in the complex numbers.

Since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a unique factorization domain, $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ divides some $x^k-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (in fact, in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, by Gauss's Lemma) if and only if it is a product of distinct cyclotomic polynomials.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the short answer:  For monic $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have $f(x) \mid x^k-1$ for some $k$ if and only if each root of $f(x)$ is distinct, has norm $1$.

Comment: Untrue. Dumb counterexample $2x-2$. You need the leading coefficient to be $\pm 1$.

Comment: More interesting point: Working in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, the statement is untrue. Look at $x^2-(6/5)x+1$, whose roots are $(3 \pm 4i)/5$. These have norm $1$, but are not root of unity. The fact that "integer coefficients, monic, all roots have norm 1" implies "roots are roots of unity" IS true; this is a theorem of Kronecker.

Comment: @David:  I like that second point! As I wrote, this was the "short answer" :)

Answer (score 2):

You want products of the [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) for the divisors of $k$.