# $4^{2^m}+6^{2^m}+9^{2^m}$ divides $4^{2^n}+6^{2^n}+9^{2^n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For any positive integer $k$, define $f(k)=4^k+6^k+9^k$. Prove that if $m,n$ are non negative integers such that $m\leq n$, then $f(2^m) | f(2^n)$.

I have tried to do long division directly/ utilize Fermat's little theorem but all with no vain. I have observed that $4^{2^n}+6^{2^n}+9^{2^n} = (2^{2^n}+3^{2^n})^2-2^{2^n} \cdot 3^{2^n}$, but I am not sure if it's useful or not.

Comment: Hint: use $(a^2+ab+b^2)(a^2-ab+b^2)=a^4+a^2b^2+b^4$ to prove $f(2^m)|f(2^{m+1})$.

Comment: I made my answer more explicit (since it seems it was not clear to someone who downvoted). Please feel free to ask questions if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can compute $$\begin{split}
f(2^m)^2-f(2^{m+1})&=2(24^{2^m}+54^{2^m}+36^{2^m})\\
&=2\cdot 6^{2^m}\cdot (4^{2^m}+6^{2^m}+9^{2^m})\\
&=2\cdot 6^{2^m}\cdot f(2^m)
\end{split}$$
Therefore, we see that $f(2^m)\mid f(2^{m+1})$ and the claim follows inductively.

Comment: More *conceptually* the inductive step is a special case of a general divisibility result for cyclotomic polynomials (something that is usually not clear from computational verifications like the above). This leads the way to broad generalizations, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Ooh, very interesting. Thank you for pointing out! I never knew it.

Answer (score 3):

The *key idea* is a [cyclotomic divisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Easy_cases_for_computation) $\,\overbrace{\Phi_n(x)\mid \Phi_n(x^{\color{#c00}p})}^{\!\!\!\!\large \text{if prime}\ p\ \nmid\ n},\,$ special case $\,\color{#c00}{p=2}, n=3,\:\!$ which when [homogenized,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20332/242) yields the  *inductive step*
$\:\!\:\!f(a,b)\mid f(a^{\color{#c00}2},b^{\color{#c00}2}),\,$ for $\,f(a,b) = a^2+ab+b^2$.

Such divisibilities may be inductively iterated and chained, i.e. for $\,\color{#c00}m \le \color{#0a0}n$

$$f(a,b)\mid f(a^2,b^2)\mid f(a^4,b^4)\mid\, \cdots\, f(a^{\color{#c00}{2^{\large m}}}\!,b^{\color{#c00}{2^{\large m}}})\mid \cdots\, f(a^{\color{#0a0}{2^{\large n}}}\!,b^{\color{#0a0}{2^{\large n}}})\qquad$$

yielding broad (cyclotomic) generalizations of the OP divisibility (case $\,a\!=\!2,b\!=\!3)$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652655/242) and (esp.) its [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42864/when-does-a-polynomial-divide-xk-1-for-some-k/42869#42869) for much on the cyclotomic aspects (including algorithms).

Comment: Enlightening, very nice!