# Detect cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

I was reading this question: [When does a polynomial divide $x^k - 1$ for some $k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42864/when-does-a-polynomial-divide-xk-1-for-some-k)

I followed the procedure given by Bill Dubuque in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42869/121097) (the "Graeffe" method) for the polynomial $f(x) = x+1$.

First you compute $g(x^2)$ and $xh(x^2)$, where $g(x^2)$ is the even part of $f(x)$ and $xh(x^2)$ is the odd part of $f(x)$.
So $$f(x) = x+1 = g(x^2)+xh(x^2) = 1+x*1$$
$$g(x) = 1,  h(x) = 1$$ 
Then you compute $g(x)^2-xh(x)^2$ and normalize it: $$f_1(x) = ||g(x)^2-xh(x)^2||= ||1-x|| = x-1$$
Now if you follow the algorithm:

1. $f_1(x) \neq f(x)$
2. $f_1(x) \neq f(-x)$
3. $f_1(x)$ is irreducible

So by the algorithm there $f(x)$ is not a cyclotomic polynomial. 
Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Seems to me that condition 2 should read $f_1(x)=(-1)^{\deg f} f(-x)$. Or you could do the normalization so that the sign of the constant term is positive?

Comment: Yep, 2nd condition should be $f_1(x) = (-1)^{deg f}f(-x)$